# Passing Multiple Arguments in a Batch FOR loop using Double Quotes?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, double-quotes, multiple-arguments

I'm using a MediaInfo CLI in a batch script and I don't know what the issue is, but I cannot get this command to work if I use a folder path that has spaces in it. I'm not new to batch scripts and have created hundreds over the years. Normally I would think that using double quotes would solve the issue, but I know it's something else related to using the "for /f" command and passing multiple arguments with double quotes. I've tried everything I could think of but still can't get it to work if I'm using a path with spaces. Without spaces it works just fine, just not with spaces.

Please Note that this is not the full batch script and is only a snippet of the offending code. I also changed the double "%%" variables to single "%" to make it easier for testing on the command line.

Also, in my batch script, instead of using "echo" I am outputting to a variable, which is why I must use the "for" command. All of which is irrelevant to this specific issue.

**WORKING EXAMPLES**

```
for /f %g in ('C:\MediaInfo.exe "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv"') do echo %g
```

.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %g in (`C:\MediaInfo.exe "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv"`) do echo %g
```

.

**NOT WORKING EXAMPLES**

```
for /f %g in ('"C:\folder with spaces\MediaInfo.exe" "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv"') do echo %g
```

.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %g in (`C:\folder with spaces\MediaInfo.exe "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv"`) do echo %g
```

Both of the "NOT WORKING" commands result in the same error...

> 'C:\folder' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: `for /f "USEBACKQ Tokens=* delims=" %g in ('"C:\folder with spaces\MediaInfo.exe" "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv"') do echo %g` OR `for /f "USEBACKQ delims=" %g in ('"C:\folder with spaces\MediaInfo.exe" "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv"') do echo %g`

Comment: note the use of **'** as opposed to **`**, which in this context is for Sets containing commands.

Comment: @T3RR0R, using `usebackq` together with `'` lets the part after `in` be interpreted as a literal string but not as a command to be executed; you will need the ` instead. Anyway, this does not help in the situation at hand...

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand, I was referring to ` enabling commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command within the set (that is the parenthesised part before `do`) of a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) is actually executed by [`cmd /C`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), which may remove potential quotes depending on their positions.
For instance, in the command line:

```cmd
for /f "delims=" %g in ('"C:\folder with spaces\MediaInfo.exe" "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv"') do echo %g
```

the outer pair of quotes is removed, leaving behind the invalid command line:

```cmd
C:\folder with spaces\MediaInfo.exe" "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv
```

If you now add an additional pair of quotes, it will work. You may even escape these quotes not to have to alter any other escaping in case:

```cmd
for /f "delims=" %g in ('^""C:\folder with spaces\MediaInfo.exe" "--Inform=General;%MenuCount%" "D:\Some Folder\filename.mkv"^"') do echo %g
```

Comment: Well, it should work, though I don't know what `MediaInfo.exe` is, so I can't tell if its command line is wrong. To me the quoted part `"--Inform=General;%MenuCount%"` looks a bit strange -- maybe it should read `--Inform^=General^;%MenuCount%` (the escaping `^` is only necessary within the `for /F` loop!). What does variable `%MenuCount%` contain? Anyway, at first you should try the command line outside of `for /F`...

Comment: Sorry I posted my comment and then deleted it because I realized I made a mistake. But yeah, your solution is working great! I spent hours on this yesterday and couldn't figure it out. All the years I been using batch scripts and this is the first time I've came across this issue. I will definitely add it to my arsenal. =)